# Filter based on annotation property in CRM WEP API

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-2016

I am using the `CRM WEB API 2016 v8.1`.

I need to filter data based on annotaion property like this one `_objectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname`

Anyone know how to do that or if it is implemented or not?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you want to filter data from (for example) a lookup field in a record.

It is possible to filter with a single record.
Example:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)?$expand=Account_Tasks($filter=endswith(subject,'1');$select=subject)
```

But it look like it's not yet possible to filter multiple record using $expand
[image]

source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607871.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bkmk_optionsOnExpand

Comment: I I got the following error message":"The string 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname'contacts'' is not a valid enumeration type constant. when request  www.example.com/api/data/v8.1/audits?$filter=_objectid_value eq Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname'contacts'

Comment: I need to filter on multiple result, like audits entity collection where _objectid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname = 'contacts'

Comment: The only way I know how to do that, is to get the audits using the "Prefer: odata.include-annotations="Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"" header.

Comment: But the filter can only be done after you get the json object

Comment: I think it's not implemented